# Apply javascript click function to toggle an HTML element

Tags: javascript, html, function, dom, addeventlistener

I am new to Javascript and trying to create a Javascript click function that will display the input element when the button is clicked and hide it when the button is clicked again. My console shows no error messages but when I click the button the input element does not hide. Again I am very new to Javascript, I appreciate any feedback!

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", load);

function load() {
  let button = document.querySelector("button");

  button.addEventListener("click", clickMe);
}

// Click Function to change the display value of the input
function clickMe() {
  let input = document.getElementById("popup");

  if (input.style.display == "none") {
    input.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    input.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- <form> I commented out the form element because it does not work to use .addEventListener inside form -->
<label for="button"></label>
<fieldset>
  <ol>
    <li><button type="button" onclick="clickMe()">Click me!</button></li>
    <li><input type="text" name="popup" id="popup" placeholder="placeholder"></li>
  </ol>
</fieldset>
<!-- </form> -->
```

Comment: Sidenote: Your `<label>` has `for="button"`, but there is no element with `id="button"`. The [`for` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/for#usage) should reference an element by its `id`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are adding the click listener twice, in HTML with `onclick` and in JavaScript with `addEventListener()`. Therefore it is executed twice for each click.

Since your listener toggles between two states, calling it twice behaves the same as calling it none at all. This is the issue you are observing.

Adding the listener only once solves this issue. Prefer to keep `addEventListener()`; reasons are stated later on.

---

Since you mentioned that you would "appreciate any feedback", I collected a few points that may be of interest:

## Good parts

### JavaScript

#### Deferring code execution with `"DOMContentLoaded"`

In StackOverflow snippets, the script is always added as `<body>`'s last element, however in other scenarios this can not be ensured.

Scripts can be added in many different ways to pages:

- Inline scripts:

  - Regular scripts.
  - `type="module"` scripts.
- External scripts:

  - With `defer`.
  - With `async`.
  - Regular scripts.
  - `type="module"` scripts.

Additionally, for regular non-deferred scripts, position of the script element in the document is also relevant.

But by using `"DOMContentLoaded"`, you ensure that all relevant elements have been loaded regardless of how the script is added to the page, which is great!

Here it is also more preferable to use `"DOMContentLoaded"` over `"load"`, since we only want to wait until the DOM has loaded; the loading of resources is irrelevant for our implementation.

#### Use of `getElementById()`

In this case, using `getElementById()` is more expressive than using `querySelector()` with an [ID selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/ID_selectors), because it conveys our intent more clearly: Getting an element by its ID. The approach of using `querySelector()` with an ID selector would be less clear at a glance.

Note that you can practically add IDs to *every* element, but reserving them for when it makes sense keeps your code complexity maintainable.

However, if your document structure allows for (subjectively) simple selectors to uniquely select elements, it may be preferable to use `querySelector()` instead of adding an ID solely to use `getElementById()`.

#### Use of modern declarator: `let`

The declarator `var` has been *de facto* deprecated in favour of `let`/`const` for various reasons, so usually the new declarators are preferred.

While `let` *may* be used in all places where `const` is used, its usage conveys a different intent:

`const` is used for a *constant reference*, whereas the reference of `let` may change during runtime.

**Sidenote**: Referenced values may still be mutated, including values referenced by `const`. Primitive values are immutable, but e.g. objects are mutable.

Regardless, learning JavaScript with `let`/`const` is usually easier and more preferable than learning it with `var`.

#### Comments!

Useful comments are always appreciated. Since your function name is not expressive, your comment provides the missing description.

However, if your function name would be expressive enough (see section "Naming conventions" below), the comment would be obsolete.

### HTML

#### Use of `type="button"`

By default, buttons have `type="submit"`, which submits the form on click. But you want to use your button as an actual button.

This could be realized by calling `event.preventDefault()` in its listener, but using `type="button"` instead makes for semantic and more expressive HTML code and keeps your JS code simpler.

Unfortunately, it ambiguates whether the button-click would submit the form when only inspecting the JS code, but this is a trade-off for keeping the JS code simple(r).

#### Use of uncommon elements

Some elements (such as `<fieldset>`) are more rare on typical (commercial?) pages but more common on document-like pages. I personally enjoy seeing these uncommon elements being used.

Note that `<fieldset>` is usually used together with `<legend>` to provide a descriptive heading for it.

#### Labelling

Your attempt of providing a label for the button is great!

A label's `for` attribute is used to reference another element by its ID. Unfortunately, your button doesn't have an ID, nor does the referenced ID `"button"` exist.

Note that a button's content may act as that button's label, so an additional label may actually not be necessary.

Your `placeholder` attribute currently only holds placeholder text, presumably because this is just a StackOverflow snippet. But providing instructions is great and improves the [user experience](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_experience).

## Feedback

### TL;DR

- Prefer `addEventListener()` over `onevent` attributes/properties.
- Prefer reverting styles over overriding with assumed values.
- Follow a naming convention, your own or an established one. This keeps names meaningful.
- Prefer browser-provided features (checkbox) over custom implementations (custom toggle button).
- Keep accessibility in mind.

### Separation of concerns

Nowadays web technologies (HTML, CSS and JS) allow for [Separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns#HTML,_CSS,_JavaScript): You can separate structural code (HTML), presentational code (CSS) and functional code (JS). Separating your code into these ["concerns"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concern_(computer_science)) allows for easier maintenance in the future.

That said, you are adding functionality to your page in two ways:

- In HTML with [`onclick`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_dont_use_these).
- In JS with [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

As mentioned before, functionality is more related to JS than HTML, so we should **prefer `addEventListener()`** to keep our concerns organized.

**Sidenote**: Adding the listener *twice* actually cancels its effect since it would be called twice per interaction, toggling back and forth between two states. Adding only one listener conveniently fixes this bug.

Using `addEventListener()` is also more preferred than assigning to the [`onclick` property (or similar)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_handler_properties), because `addEventListener()` ...

- Allows adding multiple listeners.
- Allows more configurations for the listener.
- Exists on many different objects, e.g. elements, `window`, `document`, etc.

### Inline styles

The [`HTMLElement.style` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style) reflects that element's inline style declarations. You hide the element by setting `style.display = "none"`, which is fine. But to unhide you *assume* that the previous value was `block`.

If the element's `display` value was *not* `block`, then your toggling behaviour may appear buggy. To fix this we should remove our assumption and just revert to the actual previous value.

We can revert to the previous value in multiple ways, but the easiest is to just remove our inline declaration:

```js
const [revertingButton, overridingButton] = document.querySelectorAll("button");

revertingButton.addEventListener("click", evt => {
  const button = evt.target.closest("button");
  const div = button.nextElementSibling;
  
  if (div.style.display === "none") {
    // Remove inline declaration
    div.style.display = "";
  } else {
    div.style.display = "none";
  }
});

overridingButton.addEventListener("click", evt => {
  const button = evt.target.closest("button");
  const div = button.nextElementSibling;
  
  if (div.style.display === "none") {
    // Override style declaration with assumption
    div.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    div.style.display = "none";
  }
});
```

```css
div {display: flex} /* Notice this declaration! */

/* Ignore; for presentational purposes */
body {font-family: sans-serif}
div::before, div::after {
  content: "";
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: block;
}
div::before {background-color: lightpink}
div::after {background-color: lightblue}
section {margin-block: .8rem}
header {
  font-size: large;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <header>Removing inline declaration</header>
  <button>Toggle visibility</button>
  <div></div>
</section>

<section>
  <header>Assuming previous value</header>
  <button>Toggle visibility</button>
  <div></div>
</section>
```

### Naming conventions

Some of your names are either confusing or not meaningful (e.g. function name `clickMe`).

This can be fixed by following a naming convention. You can either decide on one by yourself, or choose (from) established naming conventions. Any naming convention is better than none. Here are some naming conventions:

- [Google's style guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsguide.html#naming): Simple and loose convention.

  - No abbreviations.
  - Meaningful over short names.
- [MDN's style guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/MDN/Writing_guidelines/Writing_style_guide/Code_style_guide/JavaScript#variables): Stricter but still quite loose convention.

  - No abbreviations.
  - Short names.
  - No articles or possessives.
  - No type information in names (no "list", "array", "map") and no [Hungarian Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation).

By following the point "meaningful names" we may implement these changes:

- Change function name `clickMe` to `toggleInputVisibility`.
- Change function name `load` to `loadHandler`, or use an [anonymous function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions#name_2) since the surrounding code (the context) provides enough meaning.

### Accessibility

It is good to practice implementing behaviours such as toggle buttons yourself, but for conciseness, uniformity and accessibility you should prefer the browser-provided features in any real-world projects. That said, let's focus on the accessibility aspect:

**Controls** (e.g. your toggling button) should indicate their state and what element they control. Referencing the controlled element is done with [`aria-controls`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Attributes/aria-controls).

**Indicating the control's state** can in our case be done with [`aria-checked`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Attributes/aria-checked) since our button is a 2-state control, or by using an `<input type="checkbox">` which natively indicates its own state.

Apart from indicating their state, checkboxes also indicate the **correct role**: Our button is of `role="button"` by default, but we effectively use it as a checkbox. Therefore this button's [`role`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles) should be [`checkbox`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/checkbox_role).

#### Labels

Controls should also **provide meaningful descriptions** regarding their actions: The text "Click me!" is not descriptive. Instead, "Toggle input visiblity" (or just "Toggle visibility") would be better. If we used a checkbox instead of a button, its description should be provided in a label that references the checkbox with its [`for` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/for).

Labels come with the *additional benefit* of increasing the interactable region for their referenced input element. For example, clicking a textfield's label focuses the textfield, or clicking a checkbox's label toggles the checkbox.

Also important to note is that ["**placeholder text is not a replacement for labels**"](https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/forms/instructions/#placeholder-text). When using input elements, *always* provide a label:

- With [`aria-labelledby`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Attributes/aria-labelledby), or
- With [`aria-label`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Attributes/aria-label), or
- With [`<label>`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label) and the `for` attribute.

Nesting an input element inside a label element is technically enough [according to the HTML specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#the-label-element), but ["generally, explicit labels are better supported"](https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/forms/labels/#associating-labels-implicitly).

#### Examples

Here is an accessible example of using a button as a visibility toggle:

```js
const button = document.querySelector("button");
button.addEventListener("click", () => {
  // ariaChecked is a string, but we want to invert its boolean equivalent
  button.ariaChecked = !(button.ariaChecked === "true");

  const input = document.getElementById(button.getAttribute("aria-controls"));
  input.style.display = button.ariaChecked === "true" ? "" : "none";
});
```

```css
/* Add visual indicator */
button::before {display: inline}
button[aria-checked=true]::before { content: "\2705  "}
button[aria-checked=false]::before { content: "\274E  "}
```

```html
<div>
  <button role="checkbox" aria-checked="true" aria-controls="button-input">Toggle visibility</button>
  <input id="button-input">
</div>
```

And here is an equivalent example but using a checkbox:

```js
const checkbox = document.querySelector("input[type=checkbox]"); // or #checkbox
// Prefer to use "change" over "click" for semantics, but both work
checkbox.addEventListener("change", () => {
  // Toggling checkedness is default behaviour

  const input = document.getElementById(checkbox.getAttribute("aria-controls"));
  input.style.display = checkbox.checked ? "" : "none";
});
```

```html
<div>
  <label for="checkbox">
    <input id="checkbox" type="checkbox" checked aria-controls="checkbox-input">Toggle visibility
  </label>
  <input id="checkbox-input">
</div>
```

Things to notice:

- In the button-example we repurpose an element to behave like another. This makes the code less readable and more confusing. The HTML in the checkbox-example is therefore more understandable.
- Toggling the checkedness comes built-in in the checkbox-example.
- Using the checkedness of a checkbox is easier than using the checkedness of an ARIA-enhanced element, because `.checked` is boolean whereas `.ariaChecked` is a string.
- Semantically, we want to react to a state change (event type `change`), not to the *cause* of a state change (event type `click`) which may have been done manually.
- The input fields in both examples are generic *for simplicity's sake*, therefore they do not have an associated label. As mentioned before, input elements should always be associated with a label in real-world scenarios.

Comment: Thank you very much for all the additional feedback and resources! I have learned a lot just from reading through this information, much appreciated!

Comment: @RachelHildebrand After re-reading I noticed: `<fieldset>` elements should be used for a set of related input elements in regards to a form, e.g. radio buttons, checkboxes. Using `<fieldset>` for presentational-only purposes should be avoided; instead, **use CSS to add borders**.

Answer (score 2):

Two things:

1. You don't need to add both the `onclick` attribute and an event listener. Just use `.addEventListener`, it is the preferred way.
2. Don't use tag selectors unless you really want to affect every `<button>` element. In your case, you should use an ID, such as `"clickMeBtn"`.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", load);

function load() {
  let button = document.querySelector("#clickMeBtn");
  button.addEventListener("click", clickMe);
}

// Click Function to change the display value of the input
function clickMe() {
  let popup = document.getElementById("popup");
  if (popup.style.display == "none") {
    popup.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    popup.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="button"></label>
  <fieldset>
    <ol>
      <li><button type="button" id="clickMeBtn">Click me!</button></li>
      <li><input type="text" id="popup" name="popup" placeholder="placeholder"></li>
    </ol>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you! This makes much more sense and it is working now!

Comment: Regarding your second point: `querySelector()` only gets the _first_ matching element, `querySelectorAll()` gets _every_ matching elements. `querySelector()` is useful if you don't want to add an `id` to the element and the element is uniquely identifiable by its position in the DOM. Since we are only provided a snippet, I agree that `getElementById()` (or equivalent) is a better choice.

Answer (score 2):

Best way to achieve this is to create a CSS class to hide and unhide the element.

```js
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function (evt) {
  document.querySelector("input").classList.toggle("hidden");
});
```

```css
.hidden{
display:none
}
```

```html
<button>click</button>
<input type=text></input>
```

Answer (score 1):

JS will execute code from top to bottom, in your code, you define function `ClickMe()` after your function `load()` so it can not call.

Just move it on.

There also other solution, that you dont need to add `addEventListener` with event `click` because in button tag already have default event click, just remove that event can solve this problem

Comment: You are correct that JS is _executed_ top-to-bottom, but function statements are _hoisted_ to the top upon interpretation and can therefore be referenced and called _before_ their definiton in the source code.